# Problem with log in after change locale, maybe relate to PAM

Tags: linux, debian, locale, pam

System information: Debian Wheezy
CPU: intel core i7 3770

I initially only had `en_US.UTF-8` as the default language. 
This morning, I changed the `/etc/local.gen` file and un-comment the `zh_CN.UTF-8` and run `locale-gen`:

```
# nano /etc/local.gen
# locale-gen
```

After that, I reboot the system, then I cannot see the log in screen. It is a black screen without any word, any sign or anything  on the screen

Then, I log into the recovery mode, and check the locale, I saw this

```
locale

LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I used `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to set the locale to `en_US.UTF-8` again (disable `zh_CN.UTF-8`), but the locale still stays in POSIX.

```
dpkg-reconfigure
```

I reinstalled the locale by using `dpkg --reinstall install locales`. It didn't help either.

```
dpkg --reinstall install locales
```

I think the default locale being set to POSIX might be the problem. 
Then I edit the `.bashrc` file (for both root and my account) and added

```
# nano ~/.bashrc
```

added

```
export LC_ALL= "en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Now I can see all locale setting being changed to `en_US.UTF-8` but I still cannot see the log in page.

I did some search, and guess might be related to this bug, which is an really old issue. 
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=330500

I looked at it, but don't know how to use it.

And this is highly possibly related to PAM.

What else can I do?

---

**Update**, I have exported the logs.
In the auth.log, I saw the following,

```
Jan 21 10:09:13 QLin gnome-keyring-daemon[3864]: couldn't allocate secure memory to keep passwords and or keys from being written to the disk
...
...
Jan 21 10:14:18 QLin polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 (system bus name :1.58, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

All log files can be found [at dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2rm33nualz5ndvb/hIdhePnBYd)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as root and see if it fixes it.

```
First boot from live cd

Mount your hardrive to the /mnt and any sub directories

# mount /dev/{root part} /mnt
# mount /dev/{usr part} /mnt/usr

chroot into your existing install
# LANG=C.UTF-8 chroot /mnt /bin/bash

# cd /etc    
# mv locale.gen locale.gen.bak
# echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > locale.gen
# locale-gen

unmount drives and reboot

# sync; sync;
# umount /mnt/usr
# umount /mnt
# reboot
```

Comment: I have tried this but it actually doesn't went through. When I try to run # locale-gen, it returns command not found. I have export the log file and attached.